# detect touchesEnded in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touch

so I have a scroll view and what I would like is that when I end my touch (touchesEnded) in this scroll view : (do something) but it doesn't detect my touchesended I don't know why. How can I solve this please .sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: If you show us, how you tried it, we can say, what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass uiScrollview like this and it should work:
In .h file:

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView {
}

@end
```

In .m file:

```
@implementation MyScrollView

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
if (!self.dragging) {
[self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
}       
[super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
@end
```

Comment: Btw this is not my own invention, saw it on many sites and tutorials, maybe you should research a little bit more on it before asking. You may have to leave out the if(self.dragging) clause, too, depending on your needs.